# How to create a stream of objects from remote JSON array via highland?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, stream, highland.js

Fetching a JSON from a url `http://foo.bar/overview` via:

```
const request = request.get('http://foo.bar/overview');
```

yields in a JSON response containing an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        narf: 'foo',
        poit: 'bar',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        narf: 'fizz',
        poit: 'buzz',
    },
]
```

I am now trying to setup a highland stream that contains each object of the array. Yet I only seem to be able to build it from the entire response of the request which seems to counterproductive of the whole stream approach in the first place.

My first naive solution was to build it via:

```
let body: [];
request.on('data', (chunk: any) => {
    body.push(chunk);
}).on('end', () => {
    const responseData = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(body).toString());
    _(responseData) // now I have the stream
});
```

Digging around I also realized that highland supports setting up a stream from a request object itself:

```
_(request).map((bufferedResponse: Buffer) => {
    const overview = <Overview[]> JSON.parse(bufferedResponse.toString()); // again this is the entire respone already
    return _(overview); // now I have the stream
});
```

How do I create a stream an array of objects from a remote JSON on the fly without using the entire response stored in memory?

Answer (score 1):

I am trying out [oboejs](http://oboejs.com/), and one can build a highland stream with it via:

```
import * as _ from 'highland';
import oboe = require('oboe');

const idStream = _((push: any, next: any) => {
    oboe({
        url: 'http://foo.bar/overview',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-Token': token,
        },
    }).node('{id narf poit}', (overview) => {
        push(null, overview.id);
        return oboe.drop;
    }).done((response) => {
        // without drop, the entire response would now be stored here       
        push(null, _.nil);
    }).fail((reason) => {
        console.error(reason);
        push(null, _.nil);
    });
});

idStream.each((id: number) => {
    console.log(id);
});
```

Prints:

```
1
2
```